# ¿Cómo controlar el modo avión desde una aplicación?

Tags: android

Alguien me puede ayudar.. soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y quiero crear una App que me permita activar el desactivar el modo avion de mi dispositivo.

He estado consultado en Google y no encuentro hasta ahora tengo este codigo pero no me funciona.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mode_status);
        togState = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle_button);

        updateUI(isAirplaneMode());

        togState.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean state = isAirplaneMode();
                toggleAirplaneMode(state);
                updateUI(!state);
            }
        });
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    public void toggleAirplaneMode(boolean state){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, state ? 0 : 1);
        }else{
            Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, state ? 0 : 1);
        }
    }

    public void updateUI(boolean state){
        if (state) {
            tvStatus.setText(STATUS_ON);
            togState.setText(TURN_OFF);
        }else{
            tvStatus.setText(STATUS_OFF);
            togState.setText(TURN_ON);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    public boolean isAirplaneMode() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            return Settings.System.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
        }else{
            return Settings.System.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Deshabilitar/habilitar el modo avión no es posible, excepto si creas una aplicación de sistema.**

```
public void toggleAirplaneMode(boolean state){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, state ? 0 : 1);
    }else{
        Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, state ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

---

El proceso para crear una aplicación de sistema en Android esta documentado en varios lugares, pero es importante saber que pueden ser de dos tipos:

> - Aplicaciones instaladas en la partición del sistema, que pueden ser manipuladas por usuarios con permisos [ROOT](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_rooting).
> - Aplicaciones firmadas con la misma clave de firma que firmó el [firmware](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware).

La segunda opción es difícil de realizar para nosotros los desarrolladores ya que no tenemos acceso a llave con la que fue firmado el  [firmware](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware).

te recomiendo revisar:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1776095

Comment: Una pregunta mas el modo avión no es como el Bluetooth que permite crear una clase para poder activarlo y desactivar con lo muestro en el ejemplo del Bluetooth.

Comment: public void on(View v){
        if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
            Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Encendido",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ya encendido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void off(View v){
        BA.disable();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Apagado" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }