# Android: Youtube api player en un service

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube-api

quiero reproducir un video de youtube y que cuando el user salga de la aplicacion el video no se pare y siga ejecutandose en un service. tengo lo siguiente pero no se como implementarlo en un service

```
      class VideoPlayerActivity : YouTubeBaseActivity(), YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    lateinit var youtubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player2)
        youtubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview)
        youtubePlayerView.initialize(Key, this)
    }

    override fun onInitializationSuccess(
            p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
            p1: YouTubePlayer?,
            p2: Boolean
    ) {
        val bundle = intent.extras
        val Url = bundle!!.getCharSequence("Url")

        p1!!.loadVideo(Url.toString())

        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, VideoService::class.java)
        startService(intent)
    }

    override fun onInitializationFailure(
            p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
            p1: YouTubeInitializationResult?
    ) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comentas :

"quiero reproducir un video de youtube y que cuando el user salga de la aplicacion el video no se pare y siga ejecutandose en un service"

**No es posible debido a una política de Youtube la cual no permite sobreponer alguna vista sobre el player cuando este se encuentra realizando la reproducción.**

De hecho si tratas de reproducir el player en segundo plano o sobrepones alguna vista se producira el error [YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason.UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason).

Comment: Me motive con eso gracias a la app de musica de Xiaomi que tiene un apartado de youtube en el cual puedes reproducir la musica y salir de la app y sigue reproduciendo o eso ya requiere otro tipo de contrato?

Comment: Así es, hay varias apps que realizan esto, pero estas son firmadas con llave con la que fue firmado el firmware.https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/224924/95 , para usuarios "mortales" jeje, esto tal vez sería complicado.